# $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{23})$ is not a Euclidean number field.

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

The problem I'm facing is that of the tittle:

> **Problem.** Prove that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{23})$ is not a Euclidean number field.

Since $23\not\equiv 1\pmod{4}$, it must be shown that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{23}]$ is not a Euclidean domain.

I know how to show that it is not norm-Euclidean, but it still could be Euclidean with a different function.

The only way I know how to prove that a domain is not Euclidean is by using Motzkin's theorem:

> **Theorem.** A domain $D$ is Euclidean if and only if
>   $\bigcap\limits_{i\in\mathbb{N}} P_0^{(i)} = \emptyset$.

Here $P_0^{(0)} = P_0 := D\setminus\{0\}$ and we define recursively $P^{(i+1)}_0 := (P^{(i)}_0)'$ for all $i\in\mathbb{N}$, where for any $P\subseteq D$ the *derived* set $P'$ of $P$ is given by $P' := \{b\in P\, ;\, \exists a\in D\text{ such that }a+bD\subseteq P\}$.

It works well for imaginary quadratic fields since they have only $1$ and $-1$ as units: Considering $K := \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ for $d < -11$ it can be shown that $P_0^{(i)} = A\setminus\{0, 1, -1\}$ for all integers $i\ge 1$, where $A$ is the ring of integers of $K$, hence by Motzkin theorem $K$ is not Euclidean.
But in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{23})$ we have too many units and I can't even determine $P_0''$.

Comment: See also http://mathoverflow.net/questions/51503/a-question-about-non-norm-euclidean-real-quadratic-fields.

Comment: You're not the only one stumped about domains like these: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1148364/what-is-the-euclidean-function-for-mathbbz-sqrt14 In fact, 22, 31, 43, 46, 47, 53, 59, 61, 62, 67, 71 also seem to be Euclidean but with no known Euclidean function.

Comment: There exists a conjecture that claims a number field $K$ is Euclidean iff it is a PID (of course, $K$ must not be of the form $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{n})$ for $n<0$). Now, it is known that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{n})$ is Euclidean iff it is a PID for, at least, $n\leq 500$. Since the quadratic class number of 23 is 1, 23 is a PID and, therefore, Euclidean.

Comment: If you succeed in proving the statement you will have disproved the Riemann conjecture for at least one L-function (see Weinberger). Good Luck.

Comment: Ángel Valencia and Franz Lemmermeyer already said it: You should read Weinbergers "On Euclidean Rings Of Algebraic Number Fields".
He was able to proof (with GRH!), that if the ring of integers of a real-quadratic numberfield is a PID, it must also be euclidean. Therefore $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{23}]$ will most likely not be euclidean. On the other hand: In case you were able to prove your "Problem", you should be able to show, that the GRH is not true. $\rightarrow$ Money money money!! ;)

Answer (score 2):

The ring ${\mathbb Z}[\sqrt{23}]$, like every real quadratic field with class number $1$ and discriminant $< 500$, is Euclidean, as was proved by Harper in his [thesis](https://escholarship.mcgill.ca/concern/theses/44558f893). Other relevant and more recent publications can be found on Ram Murty's homepage; see e.g. [here](https://www.mast.queensu.ca/%7Emurty/harper-murty.pdf) or [here](https://mast.queensu.ca/%7Emurty/murty-srinivas-subramani.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

What I'm about to say is based on two results I have not verified for myself. First, I take it on faith that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{23}]$ is a principal ideal domain and therefore a unique factorization domain. Second, that if a ring is Euclidean it has a universal side divisor, and that [an element of minimum norm among non-units in an Euclidean ring is a universal side divisor](http://commalg.subwiki.org/wiki/Element_of_minimum_norm_among_non-units_in_Euclidean_ring_is_a_universal_side_divisor).

Since $N(5 + \sqrt{23}) = 2$ and we're dealing with a unique factorization domain, it follows that any number in this domain with even norm is divisible by $5 + \sqrt{23}$. If a number in this domain has odd norm, then it suffices to add or subtract $1$ to it to make it a number of even norm.

Then for $\gcd(a, b)$ where $a \neq 0$ and $b = 5 + \sqrt{23}$, we can always find a suitable $q \neq 0$ such that $a = qb \pm 1$; obviously $|N(a)| \geq 1$. Therefore $5 + \sqrt{23}$ is a universal side divisor and therefore also $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{23}]$ is an Euclidean domain.

I take your word for it that you can prove that this domain is not norm-Euclidean. I'm guessing the minimal example of norm-Euclidean failure is $\gcd(4 + \sqrt{23}, 5)$, you'll let me know if that's wright or wrong. I have no idea what the Euclidean function could be.

Comment: You write that "if a ring is Euclidean then" and then you use the converse. Blame it on these universal side divisors.

Comment: @franz The way I'm understanding this answer, he should have put a "third" in there. I also get this nagging feeling that he's been ensnared by some kind of circular reasoning.

Comment: @franzlemmermeyer I am aware of your suggestions for a better term for these numbers. But the source I cite uses this term, so I guess I'm stuck with it. Unless you write up something better using your better term?

Comment: @RobertSoupe What specific passage in my answer makes you think I've fallen into the trap of circular reasoning?

Comment: I'm not sure, it's something elusive. Though it does seem a bit too easy how you determine the divisibility of all numbers with even norm.

Comment: @Mr. Brooks: you write that "if a ring is Euclidean, then it has a universal side divisor" a,d then conclude from the existence of a universal side divisor that the ring is Euclidean.This is not circular, it is a matter of using the converse of a correct statement.

Comment: @franzlemmermeyer Thanks, I hope the OP sees it that way, too.