# showing that $\mathbb Z [\sqrt{14}]$ is not euclidean regarding usual norm using only 2 and 1 + $\sqrt{14}$.

Tags: ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory, euclidean-domain

I'm trying to prove $\mathbb Z [\sqrt{14}]$ is not euclidean regarding the Norm $N(a+b\sqrt{14})=|a^2-14b^2|$ using $2$ and $1+\sqrt{14}$.
I know how to prove it for the Gaussian integer case and I know that I have to find an Ideal in $\mathbb Z [\sqrt{14}]$ that is not principal using $2$ and $1+\sqrt{14}$ but I'm stuck here:

MY ATTEMPT:
let $I= a + b\sqrt{14}$ be a principal ideal, then $2 = x(a + b\sqrt{14})$ and $1+\sqrt{14} = y(a + b\sqrt{14})$ where $x,y \in \mathbb Z [\sqrt{14}]$.
Then $4=N(x)|a^2-14b^2|$ and $13=N(y)|a^2-14b^2|$. This is where I'm stuck.
what do i do or what's the way to prove something is not an euclidean domain using two of its elements?
any help would be appreciated...

Comment: Which is exactly the question? To show that the map $x\to N(x)$ is not an euclidean norm? Or that the ring $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{14}]$ is not euclidean / is not factorial? When you start with "*let $I=(a+b\sqrt{14})$ be a principal ideal*" what are $a,b$, and why should $I$ divide / include $2$ and $1+\sqrt{14}$? Is $I$ in fact $(2, 1+\sqrt {14})$ and we suppose that it is principal?

Comment: You say you know that you "have to find an ideal in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{14}]$ that is not principle" but you don't say *why* that is the appropriate strategy. The definition of a Euclidean ring does not mention ideals. Do you have some reason why directly applying the definition is not the correct strategy?

Comment: oh sorry, the problem is "show that Z[√14] is not an euclidean domain". since every euclidean domain is a PID, if i can show that Z[√14] is not a PID then its not euclidean, am I right?

Comment: @mmdmxi: $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{14}]$ IS EUCLIDEAN but it is not norm-Euclidean (the function which  plays the role of the known numerical function in $\Bbb Z$ is not the absolute value of the norm). You can see this in **About Euclidean rings**, Pierre Samuel  *Journal of Algebra **19** p.282-301 (1971).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asking two different questions: is $\mathbf Z[\sqrt{14}]$ not *norm*-Euclidean and is $\mathbf Z[\sqrt{14}]$ not Euclidean? The answers are "yes" and "no":  it isn't Euclidean with respect to the absolute value of its norm function, but it is Euclidean with respect to another function.

It is hopeless to approach these problems by showing $\mathbf Z[\sqrt{14}]$ is not a PID since it actually *is* a PID. To prove that, I would use algebraic number theory: class number bounds imply $\mathbf Q(\sqrt{14})$ has class number $1$, so its ring of integers $\mathbf Z[\sqrt{14}]$ is a PID. But this may be a rather advanced method depending on your background.

That $\mathbf Z[\sqrt{14}]$ is not norm-Euclidean is simple to show. See Theorem 5.8 [here](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/ringtheory/euclideanrk.pdf).  It turns out that $\mathbf Z[\sqrt{14}]$ *is* a Euclidean domain with respect to a function other than the absolute value of the norm, and this is a theorem of Malcolm Harper.  See [here](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/S0008414X00031631).  This has been discussed on MSE [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1148364/what-is-the-euclidean-function-for-mathbbz-sqrt14).

Comment: Thanks that helped me alot